# How to filter array of object by objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have array of objects:

```
let response = [{"id": 1, "name": "Alise", "price": 400, "category": 4}];
```

Also I have some arrays for filtering:

```
let names = ["Jessy", "Megan"];
let prices = [300, 500];
let category = [1,2,4];
```

I need to filter array by these arrays with condition AND between `names, prices, category` and with condition `OR` between elements in each array: `Jessy`OR `Megan` .etc

**I made this solution:**

```
const filterByCategory = (response: IResponse[], filterBy: any[]) => response.filter((e: IResponse) => filterBy.indexOf(e.category) > -1);
const filterByPrice =  (response: IResponse[], filterBy: any[]) => response.filter((e: IResponse) => e.price in filterBy);
```

Then I dont know how to make call better:

**One way:**

```
filter() {
  let filtered = filterByCategory(response, category);
  filtered = filterByPrice(filtered, prices);
}
```

**Second:**

```
filter() {
   let filtered = [];
   if (category && category.length) {
      filtered = filterByCategory(response, category);
   }

   if (prices && prices.length) {
       filtered = filterByCategory(filtered, category);
   }

}
```

**Third:**

```
let filtered = response.filter((element) => {
    return category && category.indexOf(e.category) > -1 && 
    prices && prices.indexOf(e.price) > -1 && etc.
});
```

- First is simple to modify logic of filtering, not changing main filter
- Second is like the first despite additional check
- Third is short est way but difficult to modify in future

Comment: I feel as though this should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com and that some of the choices are very opinion-based

Comment: At the least, this should explicitly state the use of TypeScript features and TypeScript specific generally accepted patterns so as to make it more relevant.  Because as it is, it's a simple one-liner that doesn't really need any embellishments, and code expression becomes a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: @user120242 if you believe it is on-topic at CR you can flag the post for moderator intervention and request migration to CR per [_this meta post_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353). I've voted to close this as **needs focus** because it feels beyond the scope of this site per [The help center page: _What topics can I ask about here?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) fulfilling `AND` condition with [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and `OR` condition with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const response = [{"id": 1, "name": "Alise", "price": 400, "category": 4},{id:2, name:'Megan', price:300, category:2}],
      name = ["Jessy", "Megan"],
      price = [300, 500],
      category = [1,2,4],
      filters = {name,price,category},
      
      
      result = response.filter(o => Object
        .entries(filters)
        .every(([key,values]) => 
          !values.length || values.some(value => o[key] == value)
        )
      )
          
console.log(result)
```

Compared to [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)-based methods it may be better scaled when (if) you'll need non-strict match (e.g. case-insensitive partial match to some keyword)

Comment: In your case names of `filters = {name,price,category}` should be the same with keys names from response, right?

Comment: Where `names...` it is `name = ["Jessy", "Megan"],`?

Comment: There is problem if any of arrays is empty (what we are looking for) it returns me empty array instead initial array

Comment: Seems I have to check `values` on `values && values.length`

Comment: @MeganClerc you should state whether it is performance or extensibility or elegance you are looking for.  All of which are dependent on the scale of your data set and your code.  If you aren't seeing any performance problems, this is a classic case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is clear, concise and maintainable.

```
const filteredItems = response.filter(e => {
    const validations = {
       containsCategory: category && category.includes(e.category),
       containsPrice: prices && prices.includes(e.price),
       containsName: names && names.includes(e.name),
    };

    return Object.values(validations).every(v => v);
});
```

You can use an object here so that you get the benefits of naming the validations as well as being able to iterate over them and check that each `validation === true`. If you defined each validation as a variable instead then you have duplicate code. e.g.

```
const filteredItems = response.filter(e => {
   const containsCategory = category && category.includes(e.category);
   const containsPrice = prices && prices.includes(e.price);
   const containsName = names && names.includes(e.name);

   return containsName && containsPrice && containsName;
});
```

Every time you want to add a validation you have to update the name in two places (the return and the definition).

It's important to note that while there are more concise ways of achieving the same result with the code that you have posted, this allows you to easily add far more validation categories in the future - whereas more concise solutions do not.

For example, you can easily add a string filter or an advanced filter function to the `validations` too:

```
const validations = {
   matchesSearchString: !searchString || e.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchSting.toLowerCase()),
   isAnAncientQueen: isAnAncientQueen(e.name),
   /* -- snip -- */
};
```

Comment: it looks like the validations object is superfluous?

Comment: The validation object is there so that you can explicitly name each validation - This makes it easier to maintain and modify in the future. If another programmer comes across the function they can easily see what is going on.

Comment: So, `find()` return undefined if there is no matches. It mean object inside `filter` can be with `undefined` values. That is why you iterate all values of object using `every` to filter only `true` values, not undefined, null, false, right? `FALSE` value is too?

Comment: Additionally you might be using a modern transpiler then you can spare the "empty condition" by using [null propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: How `null propagation ` is useful in my case?

Comment: @MeganClerc .includes() will return false if it is not found.

Comment: @Dylan Kerler which way is more performance?

Comment: I dont know why, but `category.includes` does not work in typescript for `number[]` array, only string

Comment: @MeganClerc I am not sure about typescript but this definitely works for numbers in javascript. For number array, if it does not work you can be more verbose and do .some(x => x === e.someNumber) and it will give the same result.

Comment: typescript supports null prop.  he means that: `names && names.includes(e.name)` could be written as `names?.includes(e.name)`.  syntax is more concise

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are more concise I'd say, but if you can leverage TypeScript's type system to make a safe and very generic solution.  Whether such an approach is preferable depends on your exact needs, with regards to type safety and maintainability.

My generic approach would be define a filter type that can be applied to any object, and then implement a single function that knows how to apply a filter to an array of arbitrary types.

For the "filter", this will work:

```js
type Filter<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: (T[P])[]
}
```

You can read this as "for every member on `T` of type `X`, `Filter<T>` will have an optional array of type `X[]` with the same name.

Then the filter function becomes:

```js
function filter<T>(items: T[], filter: Filter<T>): T[]{
    // interim result for easier debugging
    let result =
        items.filter(
            item => {
                // check each member in the filter
                for (let key in filter) {
                    let valueInFilter = filter[key];
                    // if it's empty, then it's OK
                    if (valueInFilter) {
                        // otherwise the value on item MUST be found in the array on filter
                        let valueInItem = item[key];
                        if (valueInFilter.indexOf(valueInItem) == -1) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // if every check passes, keep the item
                return true;
            }
        );

    return result;
}
```

Putting it all together it'd look like this:

```js
let responses: IResponse[] = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Alise", "price": 400, "category": 4 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Bob", "price": 300, "category": 2 }
];

let someFilter: Filter<IResponse> = {
    id: [1, 2, 4],

    price: [300]
};

console.log(filter(responses, someFilter))
```

I put this together on the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=43&ssc=2&pln=24&pc=1#), so you can see that all the type checking works.

Comment: As much as I like what you're saying, this tiny one liner that I'm guessing is a throwaway one time filter in the code (looks like it), turned into a a large chunk of code like that seems like overkill.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need to apply this sort of logic to lots of different types (more than just IResponse) it's crazy overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the key and values and check with `includes` and check with all filter function the object.

```js
let
    filter = ([key, values]) => o => !values.length || values.includes(o[key]),
    constraints = {
        id: [], // empty - take all values
        name: ["Jessy", "Megan"],
        price: [300, 500],
        category: [1, 2, 4]
    }
    filters = Object.entries(constraints).map(filter),
    response = [{ id: 1, name: "Alise", price: 400, category: 4 }, { id: 2, name: "Megan", price: 300, category: 4 }],
    result = response.filter(o => filters.every(fn => fn(o)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is more optimized solution, thank you, but more complecated, for example I dont get this line: `filters = [['name', names], ['price', prices], ['category', category]].map(filter),`

Comment: it combines the key of the objects with the related values array. usually an object with key and values is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.includes` is your *OR* filter between collection values, while `&&` is the *AND* filter you're looking for:

```js
let response = [{"id": 1, "name": "Megan", "price": 500, "category": 4}];

let names = ["Jessy", "Megan"];
let prices = [300, 500];
let category = [1,2,4];

const filteredItems = response.filter(item => {
  return names.includes(item.name) && 
      prices.includes(item.price) &&
      category.includes(item.category);
});

console.log(filteredItems)
```

Comment: I'd say that's not very easy to scale when there're many properties you need to filter upon